# displayName won't set despite allowing set

Tags: swift, xcode, appkit, nsdocument

When trying to set displayName on document using `self.view.window?.windowController?.document?.displayName = "test"`

I get "Cannot assign to property: 'displayName' is a get-only property" error.

Comment: What kind of object is document? In the document object ```displayName``` is set as something like ```private(set) var displayName: String?``` which means you can't set this property outside of the ```Object``` class.

Comment: `document` in `NSWindowController` is declared as `AnyObject`. And many classes contain a `displayName` property. You have to be more specific and tell the compiler what it actually is.

Comment: @vadian So how would get the NSDocument to set "displayName"?

Comment: See [Type Casting](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html)